# remove unwanted html tag nginx

Tags: xslt, nginx, proxy

I have a nginx proxy and I would like to remove an html tag from the website I proxy. I can't touch that website code.

The problem is that I use the debian package nginx-extras with xslt but the html from the website is bad built for the xml standard.

Do you have an idea without patching or recompiling nginx ? I would like to keep the nginx deb package for now.

Answer (score 0):

According to http://packages.debian.org/sid/nginx-extras you should be able to use [HttpSubModule](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpSubModule) or [HttpSubsModule](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpSubsModule) without recompiling.

Comment: I chose the nginx-extras from dotdeb for Wheezy. It seems more stable than a sid. Thanks.